# subversion commit hook fails with cygwin

Tags: svn, cygwin

We have some custom subversion pre and post commit hooks that work fine on our production server.

For developer testing I am using cywgin. Up until recently, the commit hooks were also working fine.

However, after running a cygwin update, the hooks are now failing with (newlines added for clarity):

```
  0 [main] svn 14820 child_info_fork::abort: 
  C:\cygwin\bin\cygcrypto-1.0.0.dll: Loaded to different address: 
  parent(0x440000) != child(0x590000)
```

Has anyone seen anything similar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is a fork failure: Subversion is attempting to fork a new process, and Windows is loading the new process with an unexpected memory layout. This is one of the fundamental problems Cygwin attempts to solve: Linux programs expect that when spawning a new process, the new process will have the same memory layout as the old one; Windows actively changes the memory layout whenever a new process is started.

[The documented solution is in the Cygwin FAQ](http://cygwin.com/faq-nochunks.html#faq.using.fixing-fork-failures).

The short version is you need to do the following:

- Exit all your Cygwin processes.  That means closing all your MinTTY windows, exiting any X servers you have running, etc.  Check task manager.
- Go to Start > Run (or hit <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>), and run `C:\cygwin\bin\dash`.
- In the window that appears, type `/bin/rebaseall` and hit <kbd>Return</kbd>.
- Go make yourself a coffee.

As you noted, reinstalling will also work; that's because doing a reinstall will run a limited Cygwin rebase in the background.

Comment: Incidentally, this has absolutely nothing to do with Subversion hooks.

Comment: For me (running MobaXterm, where you cannot start a separate dash), `apt-cyg rebase` from a normal terminal window fixed the very same issue of "cygcrypto-1.0.0.dll: Loaded to different address". As with the reinstall, this will "run a limited Cygwin rebase in the background".

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling subversion fixed this.